# OpenAI Gym error running demo from intro page

Tags: google-colaboratory

I installed OpenAI Gym and attempted to run the getting-started cart-pole demo (https://gym.openai.com/docs/). (I'm running in a Colab notebook.)

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
```

This doesn't learn, but it should display the cart and pole.

When I run it I get a warning and an error.

```
WARN: gym.spaces.Box autodetected dtype as <class 'numpy.float32'>. Please provide explicit dtype.
```

The error is triggered by `env.render()`. At the bottom of the Traceback is

```
Error occured while running `from pyglet.gl import *`
The original exception was:

ImportError: Library "GL" not found.
```

I had installed pyOpenGL with the following.

```
!pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
```

I'd appreciate help with both the warning and the error.  Is there another GL library I should install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Colab is run in the cloud. It can't send the graphic display back to your monitor.

You can try running it with local runtime.
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Comment: Didn't know about the local runtime option. I'll try it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get this window?

[image: window]

If yes then try to add this import:

```
import time
```

and this line of Code within the for-loop:

```
time.sleep(0.3)
```

> Thing is that the pole runs out of view rather quick, so it seems like
>   the Environment did not run at all.

Comment: Didn't know about the local runtime option. I'll try it.  Thanks.